# Raspberry PI4 and RS232 adapter cable: how to send serial commands

Tags: arduino, serial, rs232, python, serial-bus

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi4 to control a syringe pump [(see datasheet here and in particular the quick start manual on page1)][1]

The connector cables I used are RJ11 from the Pump to RS232 (from the manufacturer) as well as a standard RS232 to USB converter cable from Benfei ([drivers can be downloaded here][2])

On Windows it worked fine after installing the drivers (was needed). The COM port was recognized and I could test the pump with Arduino.

On my Raspberry I am not getting it to work.

I am this far:
The RS232 adapter is recognized:

> ```
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port / Mobile Action MA-8910P
> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> ```

```
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep "tty" [  960.932258] usb 1-1.3: pl2303
> converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

When using this bare minimum code example:

```
import time
import serial

Serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate = 19200, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1)
#Rate Units
#mL/hr - MH
#µL/hr - UH
#mL/min - MM
#µL/min - UM

def test_syringe(diameter = 10.00, pumping_rate = 10.00, pumping_rate_unit = 'MH', volume_to_dispense = 20.00):
    Serial.write(("DIA " + str(diameter) + "\n").encode())
    message = Serial.read()
    print(message.decode())
    Serial.write("DIA \r".encode())
    message = Serial.read()
    print(message.decode())
    Serial.write("RAT ".encode() + str(pumping_rate).encode() + " ".encode() + pumping_rate_unit.encode())
    Serial.write("VOL ".encode() + str(volume_to_dispense).encode())
    Serial.write("DIR INF".encode())
    Serial.write("RUN \n".encode())


test_syringe()
```

I get at least some feedback from the pump:

```
b'\x02'
0
```

But it is not starting. The linux driver is only available for Redhat. I'm thinking about purchasing another RS232 adapter cable.

Is the code with the carrier return corect?
[1]: https://www.syringepump.com/download/NE-500%20OEM%20Syringe%20Pump%20User%20Manual%20V3.9.pdf
[2]: https://www.think-benfei.com/p_driver.html

Comment: Your example is not so minimal. Try sending simple binary strings `b"like this"` without encoding/formatting, and reproduce exactly what the Arduino did.

Comment: Also check how much data `Serial.read()` tries to read. In general you need to know how many bytes you want to read, or read one at a time until you get some kind of ending byte

Comment: Something like `Serial.read_until(ETX)` where ETX = 0x03 might be helpful to read an entire reply.

Answer (score 2):

Controlling electronic devices with a computer is not an electrical engineering question.

The manual has a section what to do if communications are not working and one of the reasons is that the pump is using  binary Safe Mode protocol and must be changed to Basic Mode protocol before trying to communicate with it in Basic Mode.

The 0x02 response from the pump is STX so it is a clear indication the pump is sending you a Safe Mode response back.